# Присвоить ID placeholder'y

Tags: html, css

Можно ли как-то присвоить id плейсхолдеру? Нужно чтобы он динамически изменялся, в зависимости от выбранной валюты. Сейчас выглядит так:

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.1" id="price" name="price" class="priceField" onchange=f("price","total","amount","price") pattern="^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$">
<div class="trading__buy-row-title2" id="PriceValBuy">USD</div>
```

Нужно id="PriceValBuy">USD< как-то добавить в плейсхолдер input'a, это возможно?

Comment: @MaximLensky а можно пример?

Comment: пожалуйста  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/web/html/element/select